# Python - Paramiko - incompatible ssh server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have an error on a script I have wrote since few months, it worked very good with a raspberry pi, but now with an orange pi I have this:

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> transport = paramiko.Transport("192.168.2.2", 22)
>>> transport.connect(username = "orangepi", password = "my_pass")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 978, in connect
    self.start_client()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 406, in start_client
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable macs)
```

I can connect in console with ssh without problem.

Somebody has an idea ?

Comment: It seems like that you don't have a common MAC algorithm between Paramiko and your SSH server implementation. Paramiko supports HMAC-SHA1, HMAC-MD5, HMAC-SHA1-96, HMAC-MD5-96.

Comment: Yes, it's weird. Thanks, I will look for a solution in this way

Comment: Is it possible to change it, to have a compatible encryption?

Comment: It may be solved by adding MACs hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com [others MAC algorithm] to your sshd_config on your Raspberry Pi, I think.

Comment: Ah ok, I see the file. `#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160` I will try to decomment it. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to restart your sshd server.

Comment: Yeah it works! I've added `hmac-sha1` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (not ssh_config) - Thank you very much, you're a guru !!

Comment: I will add it as definitive answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check if any of those MACs algorithms are available on your SSH server (sshd_config, key: MACs) :

- HMAC-SHA1
- HMAC-MD5
- HMAC-SHA1-96
- HMAC-MD5-96.

They are **needed** in order for Paramiko to connect to your SSH server.

Answer (score 6):

On your **remote** server, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and **add a `MACs` line or append to the existing one**, with one or more of `hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96` (values are comma-separated), for example:

```
MACs hmac-sha1
```

Now **restart sshd**: `sudo systemctl restart ssh`.

Comment: Note that this is a security risk (tiny though), most of the other MACs are based on more secure hashes.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions do not work, you need to upgrade Paramiko as found out by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561792/paramiko-incompatible-ssh-server-no-acceptable-macs).