# Paramiko - Incompatible SSH server (no acceptable macs)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I've been using paramiko for a while and everything has worked as expected, but when I moved out of my testing environment, I got this error when opening an ssh session

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable macs)
```

After tracing down the error, I noticed that on my remote server, I'm missing some entries in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Neither of my setups have these MACs listed:

- HMAC-SHA1
- HMAC-MD5
- HMAC-SHA1-96
- HMAC-MD5-96

However, it works in one and not the other. What could be causing this? I don't have rsa keys saved in either one (remote server does not allow for writing).

Remote server's `sshd_config`

```
#
# Allow Ciphers and MACs
#
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128
MACs umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
```

`RemoteAccess.py`

```
class RemoteAccess():
    def __init__(self, host="abc123", username="abc", password="123"):
        self.name = host
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.load_system_host_keys()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
```

Links I've referenced:

[Python - Paramiko - incompatible ssh server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399335/python-paramiko-incompatible-ssh-server)

[paramiko Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286929/paramiko-incompatible-ssh-peer-no-acceptable-kex-algorithm/32691055#32691055)

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: which is your paramiko version?

Comment: The question is "What is causing this error message, even with the same sshd_config file?" The working setup has paramiko 1.16.0 and the non-working setup has paramiko 1.15.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, paramiko1.15.1 would complain about incompatible MACs. paramiko1.16.0 did not. This was fixed by copying 1.16.0 files to its installation location.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko
```

Changelog for paramiko versions can be found here:
http://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html

Comment: Yes, the reason is that `hmac-sha2-*` support was added in 1.16 (see Feature #356 in the link above)